# Installing a music server on raspbian, no stand alone

Tags: raspbian, audio, media-server, web-interface

I would like to install a music server that can play music stored on a HDD, and that offers a Web GUI accessible from a smartphone.

That sounds like Volumio, Raspify & co, but I would like this to be on top of raspbian, not a stand-alone os, that way I could still surf and play videos with the main OS.

Has anyone got an idea?

Comment: Hello flag, did the answer help or did you find another way? Please feel free to share your experience by writing your own answer and/or consider voting the existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Music Player Daemon MPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon) or [Mopidy](https://www.mopidy.com/) certainly allow you to do exactly this. Both can be set up on virtually any of the Raspberries' OS and offer Jukebox functionality while maintaining you to use the Pi for other tasks too.

A wide range of clients to allow for the remote control from the local machine or remote appliances such as tablets or smart phones. Those clients are available with command line, graphical or web based interfaces. There will be one to serve your needs.